# glXSwapBuffers glitchy timing

Tags: c++, timing

I have been getting very glitchy timings in my render loop causing rendering to stutter. I have set up timing around my `glXSwapBuffers` call like so:

```
Timer timer;
glXSwapBuffers(display, window);
timer();
if (timer.elapsed_seconds > 0.1)
 printf("stutter(%f)\n\r", timer.elapsed_seconds);
```

And am getting results like:

```
stutter(0.109081)
stutter(0.108956)
stutter(0.662115)
stutter(0.759556)
stutter(0.657789)
stutter(0.283185)
stutter(0.105581)
stutter(0.106285)
stutter(0.572289)
stutter(0.199908)
stutter(0.218540)
stutter(0.752033)
stutter(0.148225)
```

What could be causing glXSwapBuffers to take so long to call? How can I fix the stuttering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing and debugging I found that my `Timer` class was computing the difference between two timestamps wrong. The `tv_nsec` component was being incorrectly divided causing `elapsedSeconds` to return varying results.

After correcting this the stuttering went away immediately.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glxswapbuffers):

> glXSwapBuffers performs an implicit glFlush before it returns.

If you do a `glFlush` and `glFinish` first, you'll likely find that the time is being taken there rather than in the buffer swap.  If so, that's because you're submitting too many GL commands, and you need to optimize your code.

Comment: If I call `glFlush` and `glFinish` the glitches in timing move to them instead of `glXSwapBuffers`. I'm not submitting many GL commands, maybe ~20 currently

Comment: @Śaeun acreáť Still, they are causing the delay, not the swap.  If you begin/flush/end around each command you can perhaps narrow it to one in particular that's problematic.